# Write orbit as graph

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have never seen such problem statement before, and I would love to know how to approach it. Look at the ODE system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{x} \\
\dot{y}
\end{pmatrix}
 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y(1-x^2-y^2) \\
x(1-x^2-y^2)
\end{pmatrix} =: f(x, y)
$$
where $f(x, y)$ is defined on $B_1(0)$.

I am asked to write the Orbit (i.e. the image) of solutions, where $(x(0), y(0))$ is in the first quadrant, as the graph of the solution of a scalar ODE. Then I am asked to write down a solution.

My thoughts were: If we can write is as a graph, we can assume $x(t) = t$. Plug this into the equation and solve $\dot{y} = t(1-t^2-y^2)$. Am I on the right track or is there an elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{\dot y}{\dot x} = \cdots
$$

Comment: So $y(x) = \frac{x^2}{2y}+C$?

Comment: No, you can't integrate $\int \frac{x}{y(x)} \, dx$ by treating $y$ as a constant! You have to solve the ODE the way you've (presumably) have been taught to solve ODEs.

Comment: Oh, of course... I kind of forgot that $y$ depends on $x$. Solution is $y(x) = \sqrt{c+x}$ i think. So far so good. But why exactly does the hint you gave me in your answer hold? Just write $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t}$ is not rigorous right?

Comment: It's just the chain rule. Or think geometrically – what's the “rise over run” of the vector $(\dot x,\dot y)$ (which is a tangent vector to the sought curve $y=y(x)$)? (And your formula isn't quite right. Did you mean to write $x^2$?)

Comment: Yes, I did mean to write $x^2$. Okay that is helpful...